# Calculate $|GL(n,q)|$ in which $n$ be a positive integer number

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> **Problem:** Let $q$ be a power of a prime number. Calculate $|GL(n,q)|$ in which $n$ be a positive integer number.

Here is the solution of Martin Isaac in his book "Finite group theory"
[image]

I didn't understanded why he conclude that "There are a total of $q^n$ row vectors of length $n$ over $F$". Could you expain it to me. Thank all!

Comment: We need to minus the cardinality of the linear subspace generated by a nonzero vector.

Comment: I understanded the way he counting row vectors, but i didn't understanded why there are a totoal of $q^n$ row vectors of length $n$ over $F$.

Comment: This is an easy combinatoric problem and I believe you can figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $q$ choices for the first element, $q$ choices for the second element of the vector and so on. Hence, by multiplication principle, total number of vectors are 
$$q\times q\times ... q=q^n$$

Hope it helps:)